# Como setar um valor de um Spinner em um objeto

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
<p:dataTable id="tabelaDisciplinasSelelecionadas" var="disciplina" value="#{disciplinaBean.droppedDisciplinas}"
                                        rendered="#{not empty disciplinaBean.droppedDisciplinas}">

    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{disciplina.idDisciplina}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Nome">
        <h:outputText value="#{disciplina.nomeDisciplina}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Código">
        <h:outputText value="#{disciplina.codigoDisciplina}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Vagas">
        <h:outputLabel for="vagas" value="Vagas: " />
            <p:spinner id="vagas" value="#{editalDisciplinaBean.editalDisciplina.vagas}"  />
    </p:column>


    <p:column style="width:32px">
        <p:commandButton update=":formDisciplina:display" oncomplete="PF('disciplinaDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{disciplina}"  target="#{disciplinaBean.disciplinaSelecionada}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

**EditalDisciplinaBean.java**

```
ManagedBean(name="editalDisciplinaBean")
@SessionScoped

public class EditalDisciplinaBean {

    private EditalDisciplina editalDisciplina;
    private EditalDisciplinaDAO editalDisciplinaDAO = new EditalDisciplinaDAO();
    private List<EditalDisciplina> lista;
    private List<EditalDisciplina> listaFiltro;

    private Edital edital;
    private Disciplina disciplina;

    public EditalDisciplina getEditalDisciplina() {
        if (editalDisciplina == null)
            editalDisciplina = new EditalDisciplina();
        return editalDisciplina;
    }

    public void setEditalDisciplina(EditalDisciplina editalDisciplina) {
        this.editalDisciplina = editalDisciplina;
    }

    public EditalDisciplinaDAO getDisciplinaDAO() {
        return editalDisciplinaDAO;
    }

    public void setDisciplinaDAO(EditalDisciplinaDAO disciplinaDAO) {
        this.editalDisciplinaDAO = disciplinaDAO;
    }

    public List<EditalDisciplina> getLista() {
        if (lista == null)
            lista = editalDisciplinaDAO.getListaEditalDisciplina();
        return lista;
    }

    public void setLista(List<EditalDisciplina> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public List<EditalDisciplina> getListaFiltro() {
        return listaFiltro;
    }

    public void setListaFiltro(List<EditalDisciplina> listaFiltro) {
        this.listaFiltro = listaFiltro;
    }

    public Edital getEdital() {
        return edital;
    }

    public void setEdital(Edital edital) {
        this.edital = edital;
    }

    public EditalDisciplinaDAO getEditalDisciplinaDAO() {
        return editalDisciplinaDAO;
    }

    public void setEditalDisciplinaDAO(EditalDisciplinaDAO editalDisciplinaDAO) {
        this.editalDisciplinaDAO = editalDisciplinaDAO;
    }

    public Disciplina getDisciplina() {
        return disciplina;
    }

    public void setDisciplina(Disciplina disciplina) {
        this.disciplina = disciplina;
    }

}
```

Vagas é um atributo da minha entidade EditalDisciplina (que é uma tabela de relacionamento muitos para muitos de Edital e Disciplina). Então pra cada linha da tabela aparece um Spinner para mim inserir o tanto de vagas para aquela disciplina, mas acontece que as vagas não ficam na disciplina, então não posso usar a variável do dataTable, então quando eu dou o Submit todos os objetos EditalDisciplina ficam com o mesmo número de vagas. Como faço para cada EditalDisciplina ter seu número de vagas?

Comment: Eu estou tentando reproduzir o seu estado, mas um conceito me foge do entendimento... Cada `EditalDisciplina` tem uma lista que armazena vároas `Disciplina`s e uma lista que guarda as vagas de cada `Disciplina`? Eu vejo um modo de vc fazer o que qr... Mas não sei se funcionaria. Colocar um Map dentro do Edital, e com um método ir adicionando cada vaga para sua Disciplina equivalente. Esse método deveria ser no botão. Já tentou algo assim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode ter um método que recebe parâmetros no seu bean, em vez de usar propriedade como você está fazendo.

Então o método procuraria o número de acordo com a displina passada por parâmetro.

O código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<p:column headerText="Vagas">
    <h:outputLabel for="vagas" value="Vagas: " />
        <p:spinner id="vagas" value="#{editalDisciplinaBean.vagasPorDisciplina(idDisciplina)}"  />
</p:column>
```

O método também pode receber a própria displina como parâmetro:

```
<p:column headerText="Vagas">
    <h:outputLabel for="vagas" value="Vagas: " />
        <p:spinner id="vagas" value="#{editalDisciplinaBean.vagasPorDisciplina(disciplina)}"  />
</p:column>
```

Calculo que atualmente `editalDisciplinaBean` contém uma instância de uma `EditalDisciplina`. Em vez disso, ele não teria nenhuma instância de EditalDisciplina mas sim buscaria esta instância conforme o parâmetro passado.

Se fosse passado o id da displina, seria algo assim:

```
public int vagasPorDisciplina(int idDisciplina) {
    return entityManager.find(EditalDisciplina.class, idDisciplina).getSingleResult().getVagas();
}
```

Comment: Vou tentar fazer dessa forma e mais tarde eu dou um feedback.

Comment: Como ficaria esse método na minha classe editalDisciplina?

Comment: @JoãoNeto É difícil dizer considerando o que eu conheço do seu código atual no bean (nada). Atualizei a resposta com uma sugestão. Considere atualizar sua pergunta com o código atual do bean.

Comment: Atualizei o código Caffé. Vou ter uma prova agora e depois tentarei dessa forma. O problema é que assim, na minha tabela eu não tenho apenas uma disciplina, são várias, então pra cada disciplina na tabela ele deveria criar um EditalDisciplina diferente, mas ele só cria um e seta a mesma vaga para todos.